# How can I get back to New Google Maps, after having opted out?

Tags: google-maps

I opted out of the New Google Maps, but I have changed my mind.

How do I get back to the new Google Maps?

Comment: Try using [this link](https://maps.google.com/maps/about/explore/?status=invite).

Comment: Tried it on an alt account and Krampus seems to be on the right track here.